# DB Image Missing & Servers Drop Dead

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jhipster

Playing with the code in [Matt Raible's Spring Cloud article](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/23/java-microservices-spring-cloud-config), I run into two problems so far.

One is that the gateway DB, one of two PostgreSQL DBs isn't up. I can't see any configuration difference in the generated code. The log files don't provide any helpful information other than  unknowhostException on the DB.

The second problem is that all servers eventually die with the exception of DBs and keycloak.

How to solve those two problems?

**Update:**

After some dipping into docker log files, I find that one app uses an older version of PostgreSQL 10 which isn't compatible with the version 11. I have to use the force option in docker rmi -f  to remove the old PostgreSQL image. I also remove other old version of PostgreSQL images. After those processes, it still complaint about version incomplatiblity. I guess that I need to remove all docker containers or images, and rebuild the app images.

Comment: What do you mean by "die"?  Is there an error message?  How much memory do you have allocated to Docker?

Comment: Thanks for your question. Those server processes disappear after I start them in less than a half of hour (verified by "docker ps"). I don't mess around the docker configuration, but only follow the steps stated in the article. Also, the box has about 40 percent memory left after I run the command "docker-compose up -d".

Comment: If you run `docker ps -a` you can see exited containers.  You can then run `docker logs <docker-container-id>` and get the logs

Comment: Thanks for the info. I find the error root (which I add in my post), just need to find a right solution.